# R, Glasso error

Tags: r, covariance

I have been trying to find the glasso matrix for a covariance matrix input link:

[image]

```
SP_glasso_matrix= Glasso(SP_covar_matrix, rho=0)
```

Warning message returned is:

> Warning message: In glasso(SP_covar_matrix, rho = 0) :   With rho=0,
>   there may be convergence problems if the input matrix   is not of full
>   rank

Is there something wrong with my covariance matrix? What is rho and how do I set it?

Comment: Please `dput` your covariance matrix instead of posting a picture.  You'll be more likely to get help then.  For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I cannot dput my data because the columns and rows are different in r than they are in the file I uploaded, and I have only been using R for 4 days, so knowing how to change this is a whole other problem, but thank you for the advice.